# How can I link a static library developed in iOS to an UWP .NET Project

Tags: c#, uwp, cross-platform, cross-language, winobjc

I have a .a static library developed in Objective-C and built for iOS.
Let's call it `Encoders.a`.

I have been able to import such library as a project into Visual Studio 2017 using the vsimporter tool of the iOS Bridge (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/ios).

Unfortunately I am not able to add the reference of such project to an UWP project that I need to work on.

I have a bunch of methods and classes in `Encoders.a` that I would like to use in my C# methods.

How can I use such methods and classes in my C# code?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What did you get from the importer? Just a stub that calls methods? I don't see this as possible, the iOS library is compiled for iOS, what happens if the library calls an iOS native method when running UWP? If you were developing an iOS application on Xamarin I can see this working, but not a UWP app.

Comment: The importer gave me just the .a static library and the .h header file

Comment: Currently, there is no related document, you could post your requirement in Windows Bridge for iOS open source on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/wiki).